# Ngx-bootstrap Dropdown not working in angular 6

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, ngx-bootstrap

Firstly i installed ngx bootstrap version 3.0.1 then in my app.module.ts i imported as follow :
**app.module.ts**

```
import { BsDropdownModule} from 'ngx-bootstrap';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [

  ],
  imports: [

    BsDropdownModule.forRoot(),

  ],
```

In my component.html i used the dropdown as follow:

```
 <div class="dropdown " dropdown>
<a class="dropdown-toggle  text-light" dropdownToggle> Manage</a>
<div class="dropdown-menu mt-2 mr-3" *dropdownMenu>
  <a class="dropdown-item"> Profile</a>
  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
  <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
  <a class="dropdown-item"><i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i>New</a>
</div>
```

But issue is that it does not open (nor working).No errors appear in chrome console. Whats confusing is that the same code is working fine in another component.
**I am using npm version 6.1.0**
**I am using ngx bootstrap version 3.0.1**

Comment: Did you add the bootstrap styles in your index.html file

Comment: yes its added in styless

Comment: here is the working link https://stackblitz.com/edit/bootstrap-dropdown-angular?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html